# X11 connection rejected because of wrong authentication - Running an application as root user from server

Tags: linux, ssh, gtk, remote-server

I have ssh to a server machine and I want to run an application as a root user. I'm getting the below error,

```
X11 connection rejected because of wrong authentication.
X11 connection rejected because of wrong authentication.
X11 connection rejected because of wrong authentication.
Unable to init server: Could not connect: Connection refused

(eog:5473): Gtk-WARNING **: cannot open display: localhost:10.0
```

**Note:**
If I ran an application as a normal user I'm could see the GUI. The server running on Debian based distro.

Comment: https://superuser.com/questions/310197/how-do-i-fix-a-cannot-open-display-error-when-opening-an-x-program-after-sshi

Comment: @SivaGuru Those settings are common and I do have the same thing and it's working if I run an application as a normal user.

Comment: If you run as a user  your "DISPLAY" and "XAUTHORITY" would be set. But when running as a root user these will be empty and these are required to run a GUI application. when running as a normal user try getting these environment values and when you run as a root user try exporting the environment variables it should mostly work

Comment: @SivaGuru Will try and update you. Thanks.